# How does SVM primal problem fit into convex optimisation standard form?

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning, lagrange-multiplier

The standard form for convex optimisation is usually depicted in the following manner
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize} \; &f_0(x) \\
\text{subject to}\; &f_i(x) \leq 0, \; i=1,...m \\
&h_i(x) = 0 \; i=1,...p
\end{aligned}
$$
In Stephen Boyd's convex optimisation book, the Lagrangian is then expressed as $L(x, \lambda, \nu)$. The whole chapter on duality utilises this standard form of the primal problem.

The SVM hard margin problem is defined as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize}& _{w,b} \frac{1}{2}||w||^2 \\
\text{subject to}& \;\;y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i)} + b) \geq 1 
\end{aligned}
$$

From this, I can see that $f_0(x)$ now becomes $f_0(w)$, but now, $f_i(x)$ is not in terms of $f_i(w,b)$. How do we reconcile this difference and find the Lagrangian with respect to this problem.

Comment: Your variable are w and b.  The $x^{(i)}$ and $y^{(i)}$ are constants.

Comment: so $w,b$ refers to $x$ in standard form $f_0(x)$?

Comment: @calveen Yes, that is correct.